# Django cannot get file from Network File Sharing folder

Tags: python, django

i am trying to access files from two different locations(*static* folder inside the app and a mounted shared folder).
Using *os.path.isfile("/mnt/nfs_client/static/image.png")* i can check that it's available.

*settings.py*

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    
DEBUG = True
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
]


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# Define a list of directories (STATICFILES_DIRS) in your settings file where Django will also look for static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ BASE_DIR / 'static', '/mnt/nfs_client/static/',]
```

when the file is available i make a *dict* and send to front-end to be displayed.

*views.py*

```
name_dict = {'name': "image-name", "icon": "/mnt/nfs_client/static/image.png", "meta": {"type": "image", 'description':"image-desc"}}
```

But i get the following:

```
Not Found: /mnt/nfs_client/static/image.png
HTTP GET /mnt/nfs_client/static/image.png 404 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:38048]
```

- Ubuntu-18.04
- Django-3.1.2
- Python-3.6.9

Comment: The browser can't (and shouldn't) know the real path name of the file. From the browser's point of view it's still `/static/image.png` while you are requesting `/mnt/nfs_client/static/image.png`. I don't think having two separate locations is a good idea though. Maybe create a symlink to the network drive from `BASE_DIR/static`?

Comment: @Selcuk creating a symlink works, thanks. Also May i ask why its not a good idea to have two/more separate locations?